# jquery ajax => Undefined index php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have problem with php.

AJAX

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
  type: "POST", // i test post, get...
  url:'TESTING.php', 
  data: {name: "alfred"},
  success: function(){  
      alert("success"); // it show "success" !... :/
    } 
});
});
```

And php

```
<?php 
//var_dump($_POST); array is empty
$name = $_POST['name']; // error line
echo $name;
?>
```

I test it on Localhost (if it is the problem). And i dont know, where is mistake.
Thanks for any help

Comment: And what are you expecting ?

Comment: Did you really use all uppercase in the filename? Also, you're POST'ing, but trying to get values from $_GET ?

Comment: You are sending the data via `POST`, but reading the `$_GET` array.

Comment: its just keying mistake i test this code with get and with post too - same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var weightd = $("#weight").val();
var user_id = <?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>;
$.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                url:"<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/ajax/index.php",
                data: { weight:weightd,user_ids:user_id},
                success:function(result){
                  $("#result1").html(result);
                  setInterval(function() {
                    $('#result1').hide('slow');
                    }, 5000);
                }});


<div id="result1"></div>
```

try to user like this

Comment: lol thanks... now i know - i must have variable and it works... thx

Answer (score 1):

Along with what the comments say about $_GET not grabbing $_POST data you sent, you are not using the return data.

```
success: function(data){ //response param
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: when i use "alert(data)" it show all html code in popup box... screen http://prntscr.com/2o7g3n

Answer (score 0):

1. You are sending the data via `POST`, not `GET` .

   Change

   ```
   $name = $_GET['name'];
   ```

   To

   ```
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   ```
2. Your callback function must have argument,

   Change

   ```
   success: function(){  
     alert("success");
   }
   ```

   To

   ```
   success: function(data){  
     alert("success"); // or whatever you wanna do
   }
   ```

Comment: any change (i test get and post... same problem)

Comment: try `alert(data)`, what are you gettomh

Answer (score 0):

Here is all code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
 </body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:'TESTING.php', 
  data: {name: "Alfred"},
success: function(data){ //response param
    alert(data);
}

});

});
</script>

<?php 
echo "Hi ";
//var_dump($_POST);
$nick = $_POST['name'];

echo $nick;
 ?>
    </body>
</html>
```